# Suppose $A\in \mathbb R$ and the product $(-3+8i) (-3+Ai)$ is also a real number ...

Tags: complex-numbers

> Suppose $A$ is a real number, and the product $(-3+8i) (-3+Ai)$ is also a real number. Find $A$ and the value of this product.
>   [This is the Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAIUv.png)
>
> *Solution for Problem 12.7:* We start by expanding the product
>   \begin{align*}
> (-3+8i)(-3+Ai)
> &= -3(-3+Ai)+8i(-3+Ai) \\
> &= 9-3Ai -24i-8A \\
> &= 9-8A-3Ai -24i
> \end{align*}
>   If this is a real number, then we must have $-3Ai+24i=0$ so $-3Ai=24i$. Dividing this by $-3$ gives us $Ai=-8i$. Since $i\ne 0$, we can also divide by $i$ to get $A=-8$. Our product is then
>   $$(-3+8i)(-3-8i)=9+24i-24i+64=73.$$

CAN YOU PLEASE EXPLAIN - How did they know that - If this is a real number then $-3Ai-24i = 0$?? (In The Solution)

Can somebody please in an easy way, step-by-step, how to solve this?

Comment: One value can be $-8$

Comment: Conjugate of $-3+8i$ may help here.

Comment: Please include the full problem statement in the body of your Question, not only in the title.  Surely this problem comes up in some context for your "Learning maths from scratch."  It would greatly improve your Question to share that context -- what related concepts have you been studying, and what makes the problem interesting or difficult for you.  That way Readers can respond in a manner suited to your studies.

Comment: Thanks for revising your Question.  Complex numbers are said to have a real part and an imaginary part, so that complex $z = x + iy$ uniquely determines real numbers $x,y$.  $z$ is then itself a *real number* if and only if its *imaginary part* $y = 0$.  (Note that the real part $x$ and the imaginary part $y$ of the complex number $z$ are always real numbers, just as a matter of how we define those terms.)

Comment: ohh! Thank You very much Sir! Understood now. :)

Comment: I have retyped the solution from the picture you included. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You probably noticed that your question was put on hold with the reason "missing context". You can read on meta what [counts as context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960). It is good that you now included that exact spot which is problematic for you. Perhaps you might also mention the source from which you copied the problem and the solution.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I purchased a book from - The Art Of Problem Solving website. The question came from their book named - Introduction To Algebra. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Expanding (multiplying out), we get

$$(-3+8i) (-3+ai)
\,= \,9-24i-3ai-8a$$ Since our result should be real we get, 
$$-24-3a=0$$ can you finish?

Comment: Feel free, dear Dr.Sonnhard Graubner, to roll back to your earlier edit.  The answer was/is fine.  I meant nothing disrespectful by editing.  I've just spent many years editing and reviewing articles and a couple texts, so I can be a rather compulsive editor! :)

Comment: thank you for editing my answer

Comment: Thank You all for replying. The doubt for me is how did they know that when the result is real, it will be = 0?